# sending multiple emails issue phpMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm trying to send multiple emails (more than 100) to `existing` as well as `non-existing` recipients, since that is what my requirement is.
I'm using phpMailer that uses Gmail SMTP server.

Recipients are stored in array, and looped through this array to add as recipients.

```
public static function mailTo($recipients)
{
    $f3 = \Base::instance();
    $user = AclHelper::getCurrentUser();
    $template= new \Template;
    $mailBody= $template->render('leave/emailTemp.html');

// When true, PHPMailer returns exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
try {
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->isHTML(true);

    $mail->addAddress($user['email']);
    $mail->addAddress("abhshrestha@growbydata.com");
    $mail->addAddress("rmali@growbydata.com");

    foreach($recipients as $recipient){
        $mail->addAddress($recipient);
    }

    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port = 465; // or 587
    $mail->Username = "growbydata.np@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "abcd";

    $mail->setFrom($user['email']);

    $userFullName = trim(ucfirst($user['firstname'])) . " " . trim(ucfirst($user['lastname']));
    $mail->FromName = $userFullName;
    $mail->Body =  $f3->get('message');
    $mail->Body .="<br>". $mailBody;
    $mail->Subject = 'Updates on leave date applied';

    $mailStatus = (boolean)$mail->send();

    if ($mailStatus === true) {
        return $mail;
    }
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    $response = array(
        'status'=>'error',
        'message'=>'Got some error while sending emails',
        'exceptions'=>$e->getMessage()
    );
    return $response;

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $response = array(
        'status'=>'error',
        'message'=>'Got some error while sending emails',
        'exceptions'=>$e->getMessage()
    );

    return $response;
}
```

}

Recipients are both `existing` addresses as well as `non-existing` eg. `abc@gbd.gbdtest`.

When I send emails to all these recipients (130+) from Gmail directly, `existing` addresses receive them.

But when I send emails to the same recipients using phpMailer, `existing` addresses also don't get emails.

Could this be because using phpMailer, emails can be only sent to 100 recipients at a time??

What could be the issue with phpMailer on this??

Comment: your host may be throttling you

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: https://sendgrid.com/blog/what-is-email-throttling/

Comment: so, contact your hosting service to see if that is the case. That is the best case scenario I can think of here.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner thank you for the resource and suggestion. I will check with my hosting service.

Comment: PHPMailer doesn't impose any recipient counts, but your server might.